# JavaScript prototype structure and objects

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, typeerror

I'm new to the prototype structure, and I'm having trouble figuring this one out. Here's my JavaScript code.

```
var Game = function ()
{
   //some variables
};
Game.prototype.block = 
{
    spawn: function () {
        var t1 = new this.inst;
    },
    inst : {
        x: 5,
        y: 0,
        type: ''
    }
};
```

When I try to create a new object "inst" I get the following error:
TypeError: object is not a function. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Your code is unusual. How are you creating a new `inst` object? The only `inst` I see is already an object on `Game.prototype.block`. The `new this.inst` will never work because `inst` is not a function.

Comment: Assume I'm a complete noob to most JavaScript and prototypes. How should I restructure my code so that it makes sense?

Comment: What do you want to ultimately accomplish?

Comment: This is a brief excerpt of a lot of code. I'm calling spawn in a "setInterval" which I want to create a new instance of the "inst object" and manipulate its properties.

Comment: If you want to create objects that inherit from the `inst` object, you can do that using `Object.create`, so you could do `var t1 = Object.create(this.inst);`, assuming you're doing something like `var game = new Game(); game.block.spawn();`

Comment: If you add that as an answer I'll select it. :)

Comment: Alright, I'll add it in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create objects that inherit from the `inst` object, you can do that using `Object.create`, with `var t1 = Object.create(this.inst);`.

```
var Game = function () {
   //some variables
};
Game.prototype.block =  {
    spawn: function () {
        var t1 = Object.create(this.inst);
    },
    inst : {
        x: 5,
        y: 0,
        type: ''
    }
};
```

So then your code would look something like this;

```
var game = new Game();

game.block.spawn();
```

And the `.spawn()` method would  have a variable that references an object that inherits from the `Game.prototype.block.inst` object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `inst` is not defined within the scope of `Game`. So, `this` which refers to `Game` doesn't have any properties called `inst`. Secondly, `inst` must be followed by `()` to indicate a call to the constructor, which you are missing here.

Comment: You don't need `()` to invoke a function when you use `new`, but I can't see how OP's `this` could refer to `Game`. At best it may refer to `Game.prototype.block`.

Comment: This is because `Game.prototype.block` is not an instance property, but rather a Singleton object already instantiated. I might be wrong though.

Comment: How would use nest functions via prototypes and still have them accessible in Game's scope?

Answer (score 0):

I guest you need a static factory method to create new "inst". is the below code what you need? you call the Game.spawn method to generate a new inst, and you can put this method in setInterval.

```
function Game() {
    //some variables
}

Game.spawn = function() {
    function Inst() {
        this.x = 5;
        this.y = 0;
        this.type = '';
    }

    return new Inst;
}

var inst1 = Game.spawn();
inst1.x = 1; //test inst1
console.log(inst1.x);
var inst2 = Game.spawn();
inst2.x = 2; //test inst2
console.log(inst2.x);
var inst3 = Game.spawn();
inst3.x = 3; //test inst 3
console.log(inst3.x);
```